# Folder redirection and sleep mode

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have a bunch of Dell computers on Windows 7, some with Intel NICs and others with Broadcom, all of which lose their network connection momentarily when resuming from sleep mode.  This fact seems to persist even when setting the NIC to not sleep ("Allow computer to turn off this device to save power" unchecked).  When a user with redirected folders is logs on they will lose their connection until they manually refresh after the NIC reconnects.  I know that I could enable Offline Files to work around this but I'd prefer to keep everything on the server.  I could alternatively disable sleep mode but that's not ideal for obvious reasons.  Are gigabit NICs simply unable to maintain a network connection in sleep mode?  What's the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confident this isn't possible. While asleep or hibernating, the system suspends devices and OS-functionality you would need to keep processing data through a NIC and up the network stack. You're best bet is to configure less aggressive power-saving settings.

Comment: Is this it?  Is this the answer?  I feel like folder redirection is common enough that someone must have some kind of strategy to deal with redirection + sleep mode.  Maybe I'm kidding myself?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this scenario when users hit the power button (defaults to sleep) or closes the lid (also defaults to sleep) or when they don't use the computer for a certain period.

I'm not sure how sleep or hibernate will work properly in a domain as Kerberos is based on time and disconnects connections that aren't used after a certain period.  The problem is when the computer comes up it still thinks everything is good so it starts throwing around old tokens.

What I have done, because sleep mode and hibernation are not conducive to a production environment, is set to Power Configuration to High Performance, then set Turn Hard Disk Off After to 0, and Lid Close does nothing/Power Button shuts down.  Lastly, I run the command: `powercfg.exe /hibernate off`.

This is especially problematic in docking stations - which could be a driver problem.  Currently there is a rollout at my work to test so I'll have to see the results.

Additionally, there is [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2918893).

Which if there are any folders redirected that contain information for the NIC it may not initialize properly - whether it be an inf, supplemental file, or a resource linked to a network location.